# What's wrong with my JavaScript code? It won't get the CharsLeft

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I'm making a E-Mail Form. It needs to get the input boxes length then subtract that from `CharsLeft` Here is my code.

```
function Characters() {
    var Chars = document.getElementById("txtMessage").length;
    var Charsleft = 500;     
    document.getElementById("Maximum").innerHTML = CharsLeft - Chars;
}


<input type="text" id="txtMessage" onkeydown="Characters()" /><br />
Characters Remaining: <label id="Maximum"></label>/500
```

**EDIT: This doesn't work in IE, why is this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to get length of `value` attribute, so change:

```
var Chars = document.getElementById("txtMessage").length;
```

to

```
var Chars = document.getElementById("txtMessage").value.length;
```

**Update::**

```
function Characters() {
    var Chars = document.getElementById("txtMessage").value.length;
    console.log(Chars);
    var Charsleft = 500;     
    document.getElementById("Maximum").innerHTML = Charsleft - Chars;
    return true;
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ee5n/)